# Select option in select box will pass to another website JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am not JS expert.. I want when I select a < option> in < select> it will pass the user to another page.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you add some more details please? Maybe show the select?

Comment: and what do you mean by 'another page'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the url whenever an option is selected, you could use something like this:

```
<select onChange="javascript:document.location=this.value;">
<option value='http://google.com'>Google</option>
<option value='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</option>
<option value='http://microsoft.com'>Microsoft</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I mean each option will pass to another URL. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: I Edited my answer to reflect your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like that:

```
<select id="theSelect">
  <option value="/pathTo/page1.html">page 1</option>
  <option value="/pathTo/page2.html">page 2</option>
</select>
```

Then on the select set an onchange event:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('theSelect');
sel.onchange = function(e){
  window.location.href = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Comment: Strange... it works here 8) And put the event handler inside the HTML is not a good habit to start with.